# Wordpress rest API custom endpoint, using Jquery .getJSON template literal, issue with only one item not showing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, template-literals

So to dive in further with what my title states, I am currently trying to display through a custom endpoint i have created in the wordpress rest API. I am able to retrieve what i need except for one portion that is always coming up undefined. I believe i am just entering what i think is the right syntax incorrectly causing an undefined result every time. Here is the custom endpoint for a search query for one location from postman. The code i am trying to translate from JSON to the template literal is the gallery portion, and i will comment more on this after the code section below:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 75,
        "post_author": "1",
        "post_date": "2020-04-29 19:28:38",
        "post_date_gmt": "2020-04-29 19:28:38",
        "post_content": "<!-- wp:quote -->\n<blockquote class=\"wp-block-quote\"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></blockquote>\n<!-- /wp:quote -->",
        "post_title": "Ogden St.",
        "post_excerpt": "",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "ping_status": "closed",
        "post_password": "",
        "post_name": "ogden-st",
        "to_ping": "",
        "pinged": "",
        "post_modified": "2020-05-07 19:09:42",
        "post_modified_gmt": "2020-05-07 19:09:42",
        "post_content_filtered": "",
        "post_parent": 0,
        "guid": "http://olson-landscaping.local/?post_type=project&#038;p=75",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "post_type": "project",
        "post_mime_type": "",
        "comment_count": "0",
        "filter": "raw",
        "acf": {
            "acreage": "1.4 Acres",
            "completed": "2017",
            "days_sun": "17",
            "photo": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ogdenST.png"
        },
        "link": "http://olson-landscaping.local/projects/ogden-st/",
        "image": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ogdenST.png",
        "gallery": [
            {
                "id": 82,
                "title": "2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak",
                "caption": "",
                "full_image_url": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-scaled.jpg",
                "thumbnail_image_url": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-150x150.jpg",
                "large_srcset": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-1024x768.jpg 1024w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-300x225.jpg 300w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-768x576.jpg 768w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-1536x1152.jpg 1536w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-2048x1536.jpg 2048w",
                "medium_srcset": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-300x225.jpg 300w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-1024x768.jpg 1024w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-768x576.jpg 768w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-1536x1152.jpg 1536w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/2018-07_large-yard-landscape-designers-daybreak-2048x1536.jpg 2048w",
                "url": "",
                "target": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 84,
                "title": "647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811",
                "caption": "",
                "full_image_url": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811.jpg",
                "thumbnail_image_url": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811-150x150.jpg",
                "large_srcset": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811.jpg 1024w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811-300x240.jpg 300w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811-768x614.jpg 768w",
                "medium_srcset": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811-300x240.jpg 300w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811-768x614.jpg 768w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/647a097e8b23088f485a848284dae811.jpg 1024w",
                "url": "",
                "target": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 85,
                "title": "landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059",
                "caption": "",
                "full_image_url": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059.jpg",
                "thumbnail_image_url": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-150x150.jpg",
                "large_srcset": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-1024x682.jpg 1024w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-300x200.jpg 300w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-768x512.jpg 768w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-1536x1024.jpg 1536w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-2048x1365.jpg 2048w",
                "medium_srcset": "http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-300x200.jpg 300w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-1024x682.jpg 1024w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-768x512.jpg 768w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-1536x1024.jpg 1536w, http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/landscape-curb-appeal-retina_retina_f09021ca6edac80b70f3a5b5092c4059-2048x1365.jpg 2048w",
                "url": "",
                "target": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now here is the code i have written to display it within a div on my page:

```
    $menuPosts =  $("#search-section");
    $('.getResults').on("click", function(e) {
      //console.log("im clicked");
      //console.log($(this).prop("value"));
      $.getJSON('http://olson-landscaping.local/wp-json/wp/v1/projects?s=' + $(this).prop("value"), posts => {
        $menuPosts.html(`
          ${posts.map(item => `


            <div class="projectFeaturedImage" style="background-image:url(${item.image});"></div>

            <p class="projectTitle">${item.post_title}</p>

            <div class="projectDescription">
              <div class="projectDescription__top">
                <div class="projectDescription__title">
                  <p>project profile</p>
                  <img src="https://olson-landscaping.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/themes/olson/resources/images/logoGreenSmall.png">
                  <p>form o.l. 1298_1</p>
                </div><!-- projectDescription__title close -->

                <div class="projectDetails">
                  <div class="projectDetail">
                  <p class="projectDetail__title">Title</p>
                  <p class="projectDetail__content">${item.post_title}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="projectDetail">
                  <p class="projectDetail__title">Acreage</p>
                  <p class="projectDetail__content">${item.acf.acreage}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="projectDetail">
                  <p class="projectDetail__title">Completed</p>
                  <p class="projectDetail__content">${item.acf.completed}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="projectDetail">
                  <p class="projectDetail__title">Days of Sun</p>
                  <p class="projectDetail__content">${item.acf.days_sun}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="projectContent">
                  <p class="projectDetail__title">Project Notes</p>
                  ${item.post_content}
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="projectDescription__bottom">scroll for more <img src="https://olson-landscaping.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/themes/olson/resources/images/arrowUp.png"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="projectFeaturedImage projectGallery" style="background-image:url(${item.gallery.full_image_url});"></div>
            <div class="projectEnd"><p>the end</p></div>


          `).join('')}
        `);
      });

    }); //json request close
```

Also as one other note here is my functions.php code to add in the custom end point as well, not sure if this will be of help to potentially change the output of the endpoint for the gallery as well

```
function project_endpoint( $request_data ) {
// setup query argument
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'project',
'posts_per_page'=> -1,
'numberposts'=> -1,
's' => $request_data['s'],
);

// get posts
$posts = get_posts($args);

// add custom field data to posts array
foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
$posts[$key]->acf = get_fields($post->ID);
$posts[$key]->link = get_permalink($post->ID);
$posts[$key]->image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
$posts[$key]->gallery = acf_photo_gallery('gallery', $post->ID);
}


return $posts;
}

// register the endpoint
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 'wp/v1', '/projects/', array(
'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
'callback' => 'project_endpoint',
)
);
});
```

Everything is coming out perfectly except for the gallery portion at the bottom in the last div of **"projectFeaturedImage"** with the `${item.gallery.full_image_url}`

Also a note i want every image to display for each post, not just one of the three available in this example shown.

Can anyone help me get the correct syntax here? I could write this out in PHP as well but I really want this to be ajax and not an animation to get each one on the page. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Its really hard to follow your code. Can you try to reduce your example to the essence? I do not see you using the gallery in your js code, yet you say this is the problem part.

Comment: It is in the bottom of the jquery portion i wrote and is this line: ```<div class="projectFeaturedImage projectGallery" style="background-image:url(${item.gallery.full_image_url});"></div>```

Comment: did you try console.logging the variable before trying to put it in the URL? At this point I am not sure if its syntax or not coming from PHP. Syntax looks ok at first glance.

Comment: I'll see what I come up with console.logging it thanks for giving it a shot I'll let you know how it comes out